Does an animation need to be loaded with a model?
I'm using assimp for my C++ rendering engine and I'm having difficulties with skeleton animations I've gone through a couple of tutorials/guides such as the skeletal animation chapter on learnopengl and skeletal animation with assimp videos by ogldev and they have a thing in common which confuses me which is how they load a animation. To me a model and animation are two separate assets so it makes sense to do this to do something like this:
auto myModel = loadModel("path/to/model");
auto myAnim = loadAnimation("path/to/animation");

And then I can just play whatever animation on whatever model by doing:
myModel->playAnimation(myAnim);

But it seems like to load an animation properly it needs to know about the model for its bones so for the tutorials they have loading of the model and animation together like this: loadFunction("path/to/animation", "path/to/model") or loadFunction("path/to/animation", modelObject) or just loadFunction("path/to/model"). Does it actually matter which way I decide to do things though? Is it mandatory that an animation needs to sort of be linked with the model it's going to be played on or is that something that can happen later after its already been loaded?

Have you tried loading the animation separately? Where do you encounter problems when you attempt this?
